# Ruby: Encapsulate an operation with Enumerable's inject method

Tags: ruby

I have such an operation to be done for a bunch of array of arrays:

```
obj = MyObject.new
[[
  #data
 ],
 [
  #data
 ],
 # ...
].inject(obj) do |memo, i|
    memo.foo_method AnotherObject.new(i[0],i[1])
  end
```

The thing that never changes is an inject's operation itself. What if it could be hidden inside a helper method in a proper way? Something like follows:

```
def my_helper_method(obj,arr)
  # obj is MyObject's instance,
  # arr - an array from the external array
  inject(obj) do |memo, i|
    memo.foo_method AnotherObject.new(i[0],i[1])
  end
end

[[
  #data
 ],
 [
  #data
 ],
 # ...
].each(&:my_helper_method)
```

How do I pass both to the helper method: MyObject's instance and an item? Is it ever possible to do when a method is turned to a block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your function definition shared in the question, you should be using something like below.  And, your function should use `arr.inject` instead of just `inject`

```
arr = [[
  #data
 ],
 [
  #data
 ],
 # ...
]

obj = MyObject.new

my_helper_method(obj, arr)
```

However, if you want to make the code inside the `inject` block re-usable, you could make use of a `Proc` as shown below:

```
block = Proc.new { |memo, i| p "Put your code here...#{memo} #{i}" }

[[
  "s"
 ],
 [
  "p"
 ],
 # ...
].inject(MyObject.new, &block)
```

If you don't like `Proc` and want to use the function, you could do something like below:

```
def f memo, i
    p "put your code here... #{memo} #{i}"
end

[[
  "s"
 ],
 [
  "p"
 ],
 # ...
].inject(MyObject.new, &method(:f))
```

Comment: Last variant is exactly the solution I was looking for. Thanks!